# gwt extjs - get the value of a radio button

Tags: gwt, extjs

i get html from designer.
i have 2 radio buttons there.

I like to get data of radio button from GWT.
I need a reference of radioButton.

```
RadioButton rb = RadioButton.wrap(Dom.getElementById("abc"));
```

but error.

how can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButton` doesn't have a method called `wrap()` -- see the [docs for RadioButton](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButton.html).

You may want to try `SimpleRadioButton`, which does have a `wrap()` -- [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimpleRadioButton.html).